# A API JLayer BasicPlayer não abre mp3 com InputStream?

Tags: java

Olá a todos gostaria de saber o que esta errado com o meu código.
A biblioteca BasicPlayer abre mp3 se usar o File, mas não abre mp3 usando InputStream! É isso mesmo?

```
 public class BasicPlayerTest implements BasicPlayerListener {
    private PrintStream out = null;

    /**
     * Entry point.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            filename to play.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicPlayerTest test = new BasicPlayerTest();
        // test.play("src/musica/demo.mp3");

        try {

            // get mp3 path
            String mp3 = "musica/demo.mp3";
            InputStream in = BasicPlayerTest.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream(mp3);
            test.play(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR!" + e,
                    "Simple Player Java", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Contructor.
     */
    public BasicPlayerTest() {
        out = System.out;
    }

    // public void play(String filename){
    public void play(InputStream filename) {
        // Instantiate BasicPlayer.
        BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
        // BasicPlayer is a BasicController.
        BasicController control = (BasicController) player;
        // Register BasicPlayerTest to BasicPlayerListener events.
        // It means that this object will be notified on BasicPlayer
        // events such as : opened(...), progress(...), stateUpdated(...)
        player.addBasicPlayerListener(this);

        try {
            // Open file, or URL or Stream (shoutcast, icecast) to play.
            // control.open(new File(filename));
            control.open(filename);

            // control.open(new URL("http://yourshoutcastserver.com:8000"));

            // Start playback in a thread.
            control.play();

            // If you want to pause/resume/pause the played file then
            // write a Swing player and just call control.pause(),
            // control.resume() or control.stop().
            // Use control.seek(bytesToSkip) to seek file
            // (i.e. fast forward and rewind). seek feature will
            // work only if underlying JavaSound SPI implements
            // skip(...). True for MP3SPI and SUN SPI's
            // (WAVE, AU, AIFF).

            // Set Volume (0 to 1.0).
            control.setGain(0.85);
            // Set Pan (-1.0 to 1.0).
            control.setPan(0.0);
        } catch (BasicPlayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open callback, stream is ready to play.
     * 
     * properties map includes audio format dependant features such as bitrate,
     * duration, frequency, channels, number of frames, vbr flag, ...
     * 
     * @param stream
     *            could be File, URL or InputStream
     * @param properties
     *            audio stream properties.
     */
    public void opened(Object stream, Map properties) {
        // Pay attention to properties. It's useful to get duration,
        // bitrate, channels, even tag such as ID3v2.
        display("opened : " + properties.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Progress callback while playing.
     * 
     * This method is called severals time per seconds while playing. properties
     * map includes audio format features such as instant bitrate, microseconds
     * position, current frame number, ...
     * 
     * @param bytesread
     *            from encoded stream.
     * @param microseconds
     *            elapsed (<b>reseted after a seek !</b>).
     * @param pcmdata
     *            PCM samples.
     * @param properties
     *            audio stream parameters.
     */
    public void progress(int bytesread, long microseconds, byte[] pcmdata,
            Map properties) {
        // Pay attention to properties. It depends on underlying JavaSound SPI
        // MP3SPI provides mp3.equalizer.
        // display("progress : " + properties.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Notification callback for basicplayer events such as opened, eom ...
     * 
     * @param event
     */
    public void stateUpdated(BasicPlayerEvent event) {
        // Notification of BasicPlayer states (opened, playing, end of media,
        // ...)
        display("stateUpdated : " + event.toString());
    }

    /**
     * A handle to the BasicPlayer, plugins may control the player through the
     * controller (play, stop, ...)
     * 
     * @param controller
     *            : a handle to the player
     */
    public void setController(BasicController controller) {
        display("setController : " + controller);
    }

    public void display(String msg) {
        if (out != null)
            out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim funciona com InputStream, um erro que notei é que faltou uma barra `/` no `String mp3` deveria ser  `String mp3 = "/musica/demo.mp3";`

Comment: ederwander primeiro muito obrigado pela atenção, por responder. é verdade faltou a barra aí sim nesse código que postei, mas queria eu que o problema fosse só esse aí. Com a barra digitada ai também não funciona! Erro: mai 03, 2016 12:48:08 PM javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer open
INFO: open(null) Eu estou usando os mp3 dentro da minha aplicação por isso preciso usar o InputStream e não o File na hora de indicar o caminho entende? Olha documentação dela aí http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/developerguide.html

Comment: Muito estranho não funcionar com InputStream essa API. Você já usou essa biblioteca antes? Com FILE funciona perfeitamente... Tenta usar aí com InputStream...

Comment: Acho que será de grande ajuda se alguém aqui conseguir fazer um pequeno exemplo apenas pra mostra funcionando com InputStream. A JLayer (jl1.0.1.jar) funciona perfeitamente tanto com File quanto com InputStream eu já testei aqui. Agora a BasicPlayer (basicplayer3.0.jar) tem milhões de exemplos na internet apenas com File nada com InputStream!!! Alguém pode ajudar aqui?

Comment: Conseguir! player.open(getClass().getResource("musica/vocal.mp3"));